# Can somebody help me with some logic?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, logic

I am unable to develop this logic, could somebody help me out with this?

I have some big logic to make that I am stuck on.

I have an XML that is totally dynamic - that is its Detail node may increase and decrease in number.
And detail nodes' sub-nodes can also increase and decrease in number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<body>
  <detail>
    <FirstName>t1 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t2</LastName>
    <Company>t3</Company>
    <Country>t4</Country>
    <Proviance>MP</Proviance>
  </detail>

  <detail>
    <FirstName>t5 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t6</LastName>
    <Company>t7</Company>
    <Country>t8</Country>
    <Proviance>t9</Proviance>
  </detail>

  <detail>
    <FirstName>t10 </FirstName>
    <LastName>t11</LastName>
    <Company>t12</Company>
    <Country>t13</Country>
    <Proviance>t14</Proviance>
  </detail>

</body>
```

I read XML like this:

```
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/TinyEditor/PreviewBody.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Now

Every time I read HTML content from the DOM like this, it is different every time:

```
      var x = tinyMCEPopup.editor.getContent().toString();
        alert(x);

the x gets the value like this (x can be different at different times) 

<p>Headline Dear <br /> <br /> <img src="Images/Untitled.png" alt="" /> <br /> <br />Dear <strong>FirstName&nbsp; <strong> LastName</strong></strong></p>
<p><strong><br /></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I am from company <strong> Company</strong> that is located in <strong> Country</strong>,&nbsp; <strong> Proviance</strong>, <strong> City.</strong></p>
<p><strong><br /></strong></p>
<p>Thanks</p>
<p><strong>FirstName</strong> <strong> LastName</strong> </p>
<p><strong><br /></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
```

Now I want to search for every detail element in XML in this HTML and want to replace text in HTML (FirstName, LastName) with the element value in XML 
nodes for each detail Node.
After that I will rewrite the formatted HTML content to the DOM.
This is the logic I am unable to develop, could somebody help me out with this?

---

My efforts:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Home/menu">
    <xsl:variable name="i"><xsl:value-of select="1+position()" /></xsl:variable>
    <script language="javascript">
        var id = '<xsl:value-of select="$i"/>';
        var firstname = '<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>';
        var lastrname = '<xsl:value-of select="lastrname"/>';
        var firstname = '<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>';
        var lastrname = '<xsl:value-of select="lastrname"/>';
        var firstname = '<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>';
        var lastrname = '<xsl:value-of select="lastrname"/>';
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('FirstName',firstname));
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('LastName',firstname));
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('tagname',firstname));
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('tagname',firstname));
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('tagname',firstname));
        $('#CurrProg-'+id).html(functionname('tagname',firstname));
    </script>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and function

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        /* load all xsl and xml file */

        xmlDoc = $.xsl.load('XML/PreviewBody.xml');
        xslHome = $.xsl.load('XSL/Preview.xsl');

        $('#Page_Content').getTransform(
    xslHome,
    xmlDoc
);

    });
```

---

```
 function textReplace(actualtext, replacementtext) {
        var actualtext = new RegExp(actualtext, 'ig');
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = x.replace(actualtext, replacementtext);

    }
```

But it doesn't work for dynamic XML, I have to fix node in advance... I want to make it at run time.

Comment: This is an ok description of the problem -- please post what you have tried so far and we can help with a question -- just a problem is to big a question for this site.

Comment: I am more of asp.net guy, unable to put tough efforts in it.

Comment: if it is not descriptive enough to understand, let me know, so that i can make it more understandable.

Comment: It is understandable.  It is just a problem.  Hire a consultant to write your program.  This is a website for answering questions not solving the whole thing.  You have not tried.  Also, I think you should learn a little about jQuery, this task becomes much easier in jQuery... maybe about 20-40 lines max.

Comment: no, you are wrong, i have tried many things for it, i can paste code too, but it doesn't work for dynamic XML, dynamically generated DOM content.

Comment: Yes, post the code you have and describe your problem.  As you can see this is getting you no-where.  Most question on SO are answered in less than an hour (often 5-10 mins).  Yours has been here with a bounty for 2 days.  If you want results take my suggestions.

Comment: you can see, i have posted my efforts for this...

Comment: Ok, I see you are about to do the transform at load time.  Now you want to do it "dynamically".  When do you want the transform to happen -- in response to an event or at an interval to check if data changes?

Comment: no, my XML can be changed by be manually and can be updated to server, so it may have different sub nodes in detail node, so i can't fix them hard coded as i did in xsl...

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use JQuery for that purpose. Its quite handy for such tasks and you don't need to craft your code for every browser.

http://www.vagrantradio.com/2009/10/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: totally agree, you don't want to have cross browser issues on top of the idea that your data is dynamic

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If the link were to break for any reason your answer, in it's current form, would become useless. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use the xslt to generate you content not your script

if you still want to do whart you do i can recocommend the forllowing: use `{FirstName}` instead  of `FirstName` as you can find it better(an occurrence fo `FirstName` which sould not be replaced) and b.t.w. drop your xslt and loop troug the xml with dom

also i don't think you are using `new RegExp()` right check manuals

b.t.w. you say for any detail elelemnt but is not posseble you must select 1 detail-element and loop trough its siblings

this is good replace code in js (don't know about jquery (sorry))

```
function textReplace(actualtext, replacementtext) {
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML.replace(actualtext,replacementtext);
}
```